# RefineryCMS integration with existing Rails 3.1+ app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator, refinerycms

I am following the guide at RefineryCMS site and when I try to rails generate refinery:cms I keep getting this error:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- refinerycms-base (LoadError)
```

The Gemfile looks as follows:
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'devise' #,'~> 1.4.0'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails'#, :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
#gem 'refinerycms'#, :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git'
gem 'refinerycms-core'#,       :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git'
  gem 'refinerycms-dashboard'#,  :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git'
  gem 'refinerycms-images'#,     :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git'
  gem 'refinerycms-pages'#,      :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git'
  gem 'refinerycms-resources'#,  :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git'
  gem 'refinerycms-settings'#,  :git => 'git://github.com/parndt/refinerycms-settings.git'
    gem 'refinerycms-generators'#, :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-generators.git'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby'#, '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19'#, :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

I tried both paths - gems from github and just gems, but not luck...

EDIT:

Had to create passwords_controller.rb and users_controller.rb with the same syntax (names change respectively):

```
class UsersController < Devise::SessionsController
end
```

Now stuck at the very last step of example at http://refinerycms.com/guides/attaching-refinery-cms-as-part-of-a-larger-rails-31x-devise

Getting :

```
uninitialized constant Refinery::Role
```

When I try to run the server for the first time..

Full trace:

```
refinerycms-core (2.0.1) lib/refinery/application_controller.rb:53:in `just_installed?'
refinerycms-core (2.0.1) lib/refinery/application_controller.rb:73:in `refinery_user_required?'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__3443719849843969127__process_action__2929810487798718614__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:67:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:67:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:594:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:594:in `call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
dragonfly (0.9.10) lib/dragonfly/cookie_monster.rb:9:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3630594588424266621__call__617064894437263144__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
dragonfly (0.9.10) lib/dragonfly/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:61:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest posting to the refinery cms google group: http://group.refinerycms.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing refinerycms-generators from your Gemfile. This gem is now obsolete as the generators were moved into refinerycms-core

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!  Did it, now I get this: /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-189b17cc0707/core/lib/refinery/core/engine.rb:32:in `refinery_inclusion!': uninitialized constant Refinery::UsersController (NameError)

Comment: made some progress: can you please have a look at edited original question?

Comment: I've issued you a pull request which answers your question with code! https://github.com/stpn/RefineryCMS_app/pull/1